# Why type argument T is not recognized while it is declared in argument?

Tags: c#, .net

Why Visual Studio cannot find T in the parent class below ?

```
class Parent
{
    private List<Object> _myChildList;
    public Parent(Type T) { 
        _myChildList = new List(T);
    }
}



class Child : Parent
{ 

    public Child(): base(typeof(SomeClass)) {



    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a generic list in the constructor?

Comment: Not really sure what you want to achieve. Start with inheriting from Parent, i.e. `class Child() : Parent`. Then try to explain what are you planning to do. This looks like really bad practice now - looks like you are trying to do more unrelated things at one place.

Comment: @Tomas Pastircak Of course I inherited from Parent, it's a just a mistypo, I fixed. In fact it's less about inheritance as it is about why parameter T is not recognized.

Comment: Did you mean to have: `_myChildList = new List<object>(T);`?

Comment: @Ivaylo Slavov I know how to create a generic list, I just wonder why if I wouldn't be able to do create it dynamically.

Comment: Then you may want `_myChildList = new List(){T};`? I still don't understand what you want to achieve though...

Comment: @user310291, the generics in .NET require for the concrete type to be known at compile time. You probably will need some reflection to instantiate a generic class at runtime - just google how to instantiate generic classes at runtime in C# and you'll see what I mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do is inheritance of a generic type, and that doesn't go through the constructor, or require a Type object. It's much simpler: you create your base class as a generic class, then inherit from a specific typed version:

```
class Parent<T>
{
    private List<T> _myChildList;
    public Parent() { 
        _myChildList = new List<T>();
    }
}

class Child : Parent<SomeClass>
{ 
    public Child() {}
}
```

The reason your original code didn't work was that your `new List(T)` was invalid for two different reasons:

1. You defined _myChildList as `List<object>`. Even if your syntax was correct and you had created a `List<SomeClass>`, the compiler would complain that `List<object>` and `List<SomeClass>` are different. They are.
2. Generics are a compile-type construct. When you define a class as `Parent<SomeClass>`, the compiler need to know what `SomeClass` is in advance. `Type` objects, however, are used to query type information at *runtime*. So if you have a `Type` object, you can't create a list of the type that is described by that type, except by using Reflection, which is a mechanism explicitly designed to do in runtime what is usually coded at compile-time.

Comment: you probably meant `_myChildList = new List<T>();` - but have forgotten the braces

Comment: @Ivaylo Slavov Thanks that's what I wanted to do so I will check as right answer. Still I'm curious to know why my syntax is refused by the compiler since T is known as "Type" and is in the scope of the parent constructor.

Comment: @Avner Shahar-Kashtan That's a very clear explanation thanks !

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to know the type at compile time, you could try this:

```
class Parent
{
    private System.Collections.IList _myChildList;
    public Parent(Type T)
    {
        Type listType = typeof(List<>);
        Type genericListType = listType.MakeGenericType(T);
        _myChildList = (System.Collections.IList)Activator.CreateInstance(genericListType);
    }
}



class Child : Parent
{

    public Child()
        : base(typeof(SomeClass))
    {



    }
}
```

I'd really advise that you use standard generics though as this method is likely to be more costly performance-wise.

Comment: Thanks very much. Yes it's better to use standard generics but your answer helps me better understand and may be usefull in some context where everything would not be completely known at design time.

Comment: Well, I'm glad to help :)